# Converting VBA formula into R1C1 format

Tags: excel, vba

Please help convert the formula below into R1C1 format:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$49"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why? [`PrintArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea) uses A1 syntax. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to set print area based on text found on a spreadsheet

Comment: It might be helpful to add more details to your question. It's a bit unclear what a potential solution would be.

Comment: @MaxF: it appears that you may be new here.  If the answer below is helpful, you should mark it as the accepted answer.  if not, you can ask a question about it with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the access to the row and column numbers, I recommend never going to full R1C1 notation as follows:

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = rc2a1(1, 1, 49, 12)
End Sub



Function rc2a1(start_row As Long, start_col As Integer, Optional end_row As Long, Optional end_col As Integer)
    Dim address As String
    address = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(start_row, start_col).address
    
    If end_row > 0 And end_col > 0 Then
      address = address & ":" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(end_row, end_col).address
    End If
    
    rc2a1 = address
End Function
```

If you have the absolute R1C1 notation, then this the approach:

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = rc2a1("r1c1:r49c12")
End Sub


Function rc2a1(reference As String)
    Dim x As Byte
    Dim refs As Variant
    Dim parts As Variant
    refs = Split(reference, ":")
    
    For x = 0 To UBound(refs)
      parts = Split(UCase(refs(x)), "C")
      parts(0) = Mid(parts(0), 2)
      refs(x) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(CLng(parts(0)), CLng(parts(1))).address
    Next
    
    rc2a1 = Join(refs, ":")
End Function
```